# UWP data persistence after uninstall the app

Tags: .net, wpf, uwp, mobile-development

In my UWP application now I store some value in the `ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings` and when I uninstall the app all the values will be lost. I need to know do we have any place to store the value which will be save and can be accessed even after I reinstall the app in the device?

I need similar like what we do it in Windows application (WPF) read/write with system registry and I understand that we can do it UWP applications.

Comment: You could store the data in some remote place, like for example in the cloud, and then use a service to read and write data to the remote storage.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for the `ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder` which allows you to save and sync settings between all installations of the same user